# Can Java and C/C++ applications share semaphores?

Tags: java, c++, c, multithreading

It is my intetintion to create a windows application with threads in C/C++ and W32 api. 
And a java applications with threads.

Both of them will have a given set of semaphores.

Can one app work with the semaphores of the other ?

Comment: Yes, if you're using named Win32 semaphores in both programs. That's pretty easy from C and C++, quite possibly more difficult from Java (e.g., you might need to use JNI, though I'm not sure).

Answer (score 4):

Java threads don't correspond necessarily to Win32 threads, nor are Java semaphores the same as Win32 semaphores (they can't be named for instance).  It would be possible to use JNI to implement a thread library, but probably more trouble than it's worth, especially since it wouldn't play well with JVM threading.  It would also be completely not portable.

Probably would be better to look into something like CORBA or RPCs depending on what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, WIN32 does have multiprocess semaphores, but you may need to create a JNI wrapper to use them from the Java side.

Look for the paragraph starting with "Multiple processes" in the "Remarks" section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682438%28v=VS.85%29.aspx .

Answer (score 1):

Before you build a whole system of applications around semaphores (as opposed to more conventional ways of IPC), consider this point.

Semaphores, unlike mutexes, do not have thread ownership.  Only the distributed and non-persistent logic of your system can tell which process "owns" a particular portion of the semaphore at a given point in time.  This means that if one of the applications is abruptly terminated (e.g., references un-allocated memory due to a defect), the defect will cascade as a deadlock or misbehavior of the whole system.  Because innocent applications will appear frozen, and the offending application gone, you may have a hard time tracing down the root cause whenever this happens.

If all you need is mutual exclusion of some short blocks of code, consider Win32 named mutexes, a database table, or file system based locks, as easier-to-manage alternatives to semaphores (in your circumstances allow any of them).

Answer (score 0):

No, threads are related to the process who belongs to. If you plan to synchronize the two applications you need to use some IPC (inter-process-communication) mechanisms

Comment: In Win32, semaphores are a form of IPC, as long as they are named.